# R and nvblas.dynlib (on a mac)

Tags: r, cuda, blas, openblas, nvblas

I have R on my mac installed via [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).  I also have openblas installed via [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/openblas.rb). I can switch between BLAS implementations as follows:

Reference blas (netlib I think):

```
ln -sf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
```

vecLib (Apple's BLAS):

```
 ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current/libBLAS.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
```

openblas (provided via homebrew):

```
brew link openblas --force
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libopenblas.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
```

Of the 3 options, openblas seems to be the fastest option (though vecLib is a very close second).

However, I want to try more power:

[image: More Power]

I [installed CUDA 6.5 from NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). This downloads a bunch of files to `/Developer/NVIDIA/` and links some of them to `/usr/local/cuda`.  I set my cuda environment variables in `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CUDA_ROOT="/usr/local/cuda/bin"
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda"
export NVBLAS_CONFIG_FILE="/Users/me/nvblas.conf"
```

I then made an "/Users/me/nvblas.conf" with the following entries:

```
NVBLAS_CPU_BLAS_LIB /usr/local/lib/libopenblas.dylib
NVBLAS_GPU_LIST ALL0
NVBLAS_TILE_DIM 2048
NVBLAS_AUTOPIN_MEM_ENABLED
```

In theory, this should point `nvblas.dylib` back to `libopenblas.dylib` for BLAS functions that are not includes in `nvblas.dylib`.

So far so good.  The next step is to link R against `nvblas.dylib`:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib/libnvblas.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
```

However, when I start R, it seems that `libRlapack.dylib` can't find all of the BLAS functions its looking for:

```
me:~ me$ R
[NVBLAS] Using devices :0 
[NVBLAS] Config parsed

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so, 6): Symbol not found: _dasum_
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

openblas works fine on its own, and provides all the functionality R is looking for, so I think the error is that `libnvblas.dylib` isn't properly falling back to `libopenblas.dylib`.

This happens no matter what CPU BLAS I points `libnvblas.dylib` at (netlib, vecLib, openblas).  Can anyone help me sort out this error?  Is there anything else I need to add to my path or link to get `libnvblas.dylib` properly working with R on a mac?

The relevant error is probably:

```
Symbol not found: _dasum_
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
```

Which looks to me like nvblas isn't forwarding `_dasum_` to openblas.

/edit:

```
otool -L /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
```

Yields:

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib:
    @rpath/libnvblas.6.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 6.5.14)
    @rpath/libcublas.6.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 6.5.14)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 635.21.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Comment: Good question. Have you checked  `otool -L /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib` ?

Comment: @MaratTalipov Added the output.  Not sure how to interpret.

Comment: It's just a way to make sure that rBlas can see the libraries it depends on. `otool` would say 'not found' against missing libraries.

Comment: CUBLAS includes a dasum implementation, so not being able to get a dasum from a host BLAS library can't be the problem . This looks much more like a Fortan versus C linakge or  symbol mangling problem to me (note the symbol name that R expects:  `_dasum_`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. Under OSX overriding the library instead of replacing the library in the R.framework solved the problem for me:

```
$ DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=y DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/lib/libnvblas.7.0.dylib R
```

Comment: This also worked for me. To save some time, you will also need nvblas.conf